# jquery mobile click() on listview

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, click

I have a problem with the listview in jquery mobile. I want to load some data from a server using JSON and fill thy listview with the items. That works fine. But when I am trying to react on a click on a new loaded item I do net get the event! I think I have to refresh the view somehow, bit do not know how.

I made a little sketch on http://jsfiddle.net/VqULm/227/

when u hit the click me button the click event on a item isn't tracked anymore. How do i get the "Wokrs" alert on the new items?

Thank u very much for reading!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try

```
    $('#listview').on('click', 'li', function() {
        alert("Works"); // id of clicked li by directly accessing DOMElement property
    });
```

with `jQuery > 1.7`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/SWknG/1/)**

**OR**

```
$('#listview li').live('click', function() {
    alert("Works"); // id of clicked li by directly accessing DOMElement property
});
```

with your jQuery version 1.6.4.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/mcm8z/)**

#### why you need this

Because. you're adding `li` within `listview` after page reload, so any event for those `li`s should `live` (for jQuery version you used) or `delegate` (jQuery > 1.7).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  Aaaah ok understand. new to script-based programming. Thought something that way! Again, thank u! SOLVED!

Answer (score 3):

If your JQM version is old (like mine- jqm 1.2.0),
and both mentioned methods are not working for you

**Try this:**

```
     <ul data-role="listview" id="myList">
       <li id="1" >text</li>
     </ul>

     //on the js code use delegate
     $('#myList').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
         alert($(this).attr('id'));
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

To remote data source and liswiew

wrap the ul element with a div

```
<div data-role="page" id="myPage">
  <form id="myform" class="ui-filterable">
    <input id="what" data-type="search" placeholder="i.e.Carpentry...">
    <div id="w_what">
      <ul id="ul_what" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data input="#what">
      </ul>
     </div>
   </form>
 </div>

$( "#ul_what" ).on( "filterablebeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
    $input = $( data.input ),
    value = $input.val(),
    html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );       // initially null 
    $('#w_what').show();  // For next search
    if ( value && value.length > 0 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
            url: "/php/getWhat.php", // Ajax url
            dataType: "json",        // json 
            data: {
                q: $input.val()      // which value to be searched
            }
        })
        .then( function ( response ) {
            $.each( response, function ( id, val ) {
                html += "<li>" + val.text + "</li>";  // json response has text element
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
    }
});

$('#ul_what').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
    var ul = $(this);          // when clicked
    $('#what').val(ul.text()); // set the value for input       
    $('#w_what').hide();       // hide the div 

 });
```

Hope helps to somenone