# How to get selected item (object) in jquery listview?

Tags: jquery, delphi, rest, listview, datasnap

I want to have a list of customer and when I click on this customer I want to get the detail on another page. I fill my jquery listview with the GetWorkerList function and it work well but when I click on my listview, I don't know how to get the goog json object of my json array ?
I'm beginner in javascript and jquerymobile and I have made this to fill my list view.

Javascript code

```
function GetWorkerList()
{
    res = serverMethods().GetWorkerList($('#pWorkerList #SearchWorkerValue').val());
    var array = res.result;
    var strarray = '';
    for (var n=0; n<array.length; n++) {
            strarray += '<li><a href="#">'
                + array[n].Name
                + ((array[n].FirstNam == null) ? '' : ' ' + array[n].FirstNam)
                + '</a>' + '</li>';
    };

    $("#lvWorker").empty();
    $("#lvWorker").append (strarray);
    $('#pWorkerList #lvWorker').listview('refresh');
}

function SelectCustomer()
{
    toto = $("#lvCustomer");
    alert('Display Customer detail');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bCustomerList').click (function (){
    GetCustomerList();
   });
  $('#lvCustomer').click (function (){
    SelectCustomer();
   });

});
```

HTML code

```
<!-- CustomerList -->
<div data-role="page" id="pCustomerList">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>LacourApps customer</h1>
        <a data-role="button" href="#pmain" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <input onclick="GetCustomerList" value="CustomerList" type="button" id="bCustomerList">
    <input id="SearchCustomerValue" value="VAS">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="lvCustomer" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: what happens when you click on your list view? Although you are clicking on the listview itself not the items in the list your code suggests that: $('#lvCustomer').click (function (){
    SelectCustomer();
   }); Where "$('#lvCustomer')" is the id of the listview.

Comment: I think you need this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10884422/800214

Comment: @Jai when I click on my list view item, it display my alert in SelectCustomer()