# add ClickListener JQuery Mobile ListView

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am not able to add clickListener to my dynamically created listView. I've tried te following at stackoverflow but it doesnt work

What is wrong and how do I solve it?

**javascript/jquery**

```
 parseContent: function() {

    $('#countries').append('<ul data-role="listview" id="mylistview" style="margin: 50px">');       
    $.each(jsonData, function(i, item) {

        console.log(item.stad); 
        $('#countries').append('<li> <img src=' + "res/flags/" + item.flag + ' id="icon">' + '<span id="listlabel">' + item.country + '</span></li>').listview().listview('refresh');
        $('#countries').hide().fadeIn(800);   
    });
    $('#countries').append('<ul>');

    /*
    $('#mylistview').on('click', function() {
        d.lg("Works"); // id of clicked li by directly accessing DOMElement property
    });
    */

     $('#mylistview').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
     });
}
```

**html**

```
   <div data-role="page" id="one">

            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">


                <div id="countries">

                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
```

[jquery mobile click() on listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884378/jquery-mobile-click-on-listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.delegate(...)` is deprectated according to the JQuery docs.

Have you tried: `$("#countries").on("click", "li", function() {})`

Answer (score 1):

Always do it like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#mylistview li', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

This is delegated event binding; it doesn't care if the element is in DOM or not. Once the element is inside said event is going to be attached to it.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Lq9fkga/

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 $("#mylistview").on("click", "li", function() {})
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.